# I can't start ubuntu due to "Windows failed to start" error with wubi

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I am unable to start Ubuntu. I have Windows and Ubuntu 12.10 installed via `wubi.exe`. This is the error message I got:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:

 1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
 2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."  
 3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance. 

 File: `\ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr`
 Status: 0xc0000098
```

Comment: @saraxue Is this happening on Windows 8? If so, see [Is wubi for Windows 8?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225048/is-wubi-for-windows-8) and [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) (and please let us know).

Comment: If you have a Linux CD you may be able to fix it ...
Read this >> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639198
Are you using Windows 8 ?