# Is wubi for Windows 8?

Tags: wubi, uefi, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to boot WUBI installed Ubuntu within Windows 8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168608/how-to-boot-wubi-installed-ubuntu-within-windows-8)
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system)

My Dell laptop shipped with Windows 8. I installed Ubuntu 12.10(64 bit) through wubi installer, the installer worked fine till the reboot demanding screen. But after the reboot, my laptop boots to a black screen with the problem stated:

" File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
  Status: 0xc000007b
  Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors. "

I checked for the specified path in my c drive(windows 8) and i found the file there.
Now, whats the problem. Is it the compatibility of wubi with windows 8 or something else??
Could anyone help