# Ubuntu Installation through wubi on ASUS X401a with Windows 8 pre-installed

Tags: 12.04, wubi, asus, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is wubi for Windows 8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225048/is-wubi-for-windows-8)

It seems that after I ran WUBI in Windows 8 that everything was correctly installed. The problem I have is when I re-boot, Windows loads some sort of boot manager that asks me what OS I want to boot from. When I select UBUNTU, I'm getting error messages. Here is what my screen says:
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software issue is the cause. To fix the problem:

1. Insert your Windows installation disk and restart
2. Choose your language settings and then click "NEXT"
3. Click repair your computer.

File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubi1dr.mbr
Status: 0xc000007b

This application or operating system couldn't be - something, something (can't read that part) required file is missing or contains errors.

So, is there something I can do to fix this? or is this a hardware issue? I've searched the forums and can't find anything about this. I've never done anything like this before so any help would be appreciated!!

Operating System: Windows 8 64-bit (6.2, Build 9200) (9200.win8_gdr.121023-1503)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       System Model: X401A1
               BIOS: X401A1.211
          Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU B980 @ 2.40GHz (2 CPUs), ~2.4GHz
             Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 3980MB RAM
          Page File: 1450MB used, 3232MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.02.9200.16384 64bit Unicode