# Problems installing Ubuntu 13.04 on Windows 8 PC

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows-8

```
Exception: Error executing command
>>command=C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe /set {59a7630e-b8b3-11e2-b90c-d3fbf29a86ca} device partition=E:
>>retval=1
>>stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.

The request is not supported.
```

Can anyone tell me what is this error?

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to install Ubuntu via wubi, so inside windows? than I have bad news for you, it will probably not work in windows 8 (check the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225048/is-wubi-for-windows-8)). try booting from a live cd/dvd, create a separate partition for Ubuntu and install it there. [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) is more info about installing Ubuntu on a machine with UEFI (which is probably the case with a windows 9 computer)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use WUBI?

As far as I know, WUBI has no support for UEFI machines and has been removed from Ubuntu 13.04.

(Phoronix:Ubuntu 13.04 To Axe The Wubi Windows Installer:
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM0MDY)

Comment: WUBI is still included in 13.04... why?... who knows.  That said, it does basically give instructions for the end user to simply reboot off of the disc instead.  Super helpful, I know.  lol