# Permission Denied on Installer

Tags: installation

When I try to install Ubuntu with wubi, it gets to about 70% but then it stops for a couple minutes. Then, it says permission denied. I already tried using a virtual drive but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding was the WUBI does not work for the current ubntu 13.04 release.
See here https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-April/036993.html

If would would like to set up a true Ubuntu dual boot (you get better performance that way because ubuntu runs on a linux formatted partition) you should look her https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot 
But basically the idea is to boot the ubuntu installer form a dvd or flash drive and then choose the option to install alongside windows during the ubuntu installation.

If you are running windows 8, than that could be another issue with wubi (but again you SHOULD NOT use wubi) see [Is wubi for Windows 8?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225048/is-wubi-for-windows-8).