# Ubuntu 12.10 wont boot with the windows installer

Tags: wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

I just installed 12.10 on my pc alongside windows 8. I followed all the direction with the windows installer but when i try to boot Ubuntu it says that it cant run it because a file is missing.

Comment: I doubt it says "a file". We like to know what file since the answer is going to depend on that.

Comment: It's probably `wubildr.mbr` and it's not missing or corrupt (even if the message says so). Wubi doesn't work with any preinstalled Windows 8 computers. There's a duplicate question somewhere about that, but basically you have to do a normal install.

Comment: @bcbc Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203903/i-cant-start-ubuntu-due-to-windows-failed-to-start-error-with-wubi) the same issue? (I am not saying I think this should be duped to that...but should they both be duped to the same thing?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think it's a windows 8 issue. For me it gave a corrupt bootloader. I think the best option is to install with vmware or virtualbox in Windows.

Or you can choose to install Windows 7 and then install it with the Windows installer.